# Error based on Remote Validation in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my controller code:

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult CheckBuildingName()
    {
        var isUnique = true;
        string _buildingName = Request.Form["buildingName"]; // put your control name here
        var connectionstring = ConnectionProvider();
        AddBuildingModel model = new AddBuildingModel();
        using (var context = new Notifier.AccountDatabase(connectionstring))
        {
            var objBuilding = (from building in context.Buildings
                               where building.buildingName == model.buildingName && building.buildingActive == true
                               select building).FirstOrDefault();

            if (objBuilding == null)
            {
                isUnique = true;


            }
            else
            {
                isUnique = false;
            }
        }
        if (isUnique == false)
        {
            return Json("Building already taken, Pleaes try with different name.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

and my model is like below:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("buildingName")]
[Remote("CheckBuildingName", "ConfigLocationController",ErrorMessage = "Building already exists!")]
public string buildingName { get; set; }
```

I am getting errors on this. The controller path cannot be found out or does not implement IController. What does that mean. Am I missing something ? Or is my code completely wrong. ? Please help

Comment: If you controller is `ConfigLocationController` then its `[Remote("CheckBuildingName", "ConfigLocation", ErrorMessage ...)]` (not `"ConfigLocationController"`)

Comment: And do not use `Request.Form` - change the method to `public JsonResult CheckBuildingName(string buildingName)`

Comment: If I change the function parameter, how should I write that in model ? Please tel as I am a fresher.

Comment: And you can simply use `bool exists = context.Buildings.Any(x => x.buildingName == buildingName && x.buildingActive); return Json(!exists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: What model? (and what do you have `AddBuildingModel model = new AddBuildingModel();` for - that's a new instance and `model.buildingName` would be `null` so your code would never work). The value of the `string buildingName` parameter will contain the value of the textbox.

Comment: Ok i got it. But in the attributes I should write this way right?  [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("buildingName")]
 [Remote("CheckBuildingName(buildingName)","ConfigLocation",ErrorMessage = "Building already exists!")]
  public string buildingName { get; set; }

Comment: No. Just `[Remote("CheckBuildingName","ConfigLocation",E‌​rrorMessage = "Building already exists!")]`

Comment: OK I will implement that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is that your `RemoteAttribute` is calling the `CheckBuildingName` method of `ConfigLocationControllerController`. Assuming that you controller is actually named `ConfigLocationController`, then you attributes need to be

```
[Display(Name = "Building Name")] // use this attribute, not DisplayName
[Remote("CheckBuildingName", "ConfigLocation",ErrorMessage = "Building already exists!")]
public string buildingName { get; set; }
```

However your method also contains errors. You initialize a new instance of a model and then use the value of its `buildingName` property (which will be `null`) in your query so it will always return `null`. In additional, you should add a parameter for the value your ajax call is submitting rather than using `Request.Form`. You method can be simply

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CheckBuildingName(string buildingName)
{
    bool exists = context.Buildings.Any(x => x.buildingName == buildingName && x.buildingActive);
    return Json(!exists, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

which will return `true` if there is no match, or `false` if there is, in which case the message you have defined in the attribute will be displayed in the view assuming you have included `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.buildingName)`