# Error when trying to set up custom validation in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I get the error message "The controller for path '/ItemController/IsAssetAvailable' was not found or does not implement IController" when trying to submit my form that has the custom validation set for it in the model using DataAnnotations.

**Controller Layout:**

[image: Controller design]

**Controller Code:**

```
public ActionResult IsAssetAvailable(string Asset_Tag_Nbr)
    {
        using (db)
        {
            try
            {
                var asset = db.Items.Single(i => i.Asset_Tag_Nbr == Asset_Tag_Nbr);
                return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Data Annotations:**

```
[Display(Name = "Asset Tag #")]
[Remote("IsAssetAvailable", "ItemController", ErrorMessage = "Asset # already exists.")]
public string Asset_Tag_Nbr { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Asset_Tag_Nbr, new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Asset_Tag_Nbr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Asset_Tag_Nbr)
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seem coming from controller name declared inside `RemoteAttribute` like this:

```
[Remote("IsAssetAvailable", "ItemController", ErrorMessage = "Asset # already exists.")]
public string Asset_Tag_Nbr { get; set; }
```

which you're using `RouteAttribute` [with 2 overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_RemoteAttribute__ctor_System_String_System_String_):

```
public RemoteAttribute (string action, string controller)
```

The `controller` parameter refers to the controller name which contains corresponding action method name, without using `Controller` suffix. Hence, you should use `RouteAttribute` parameter like example below:

```
[Display(Name = "Asset Tag #")]
[Remote("IsAssetAvailable", "Item", ErrorMessage = "Asset # already exists.")]
public string Asset_Tag_Nbr { get; set; }
```

Related issue:

[Error based on Remote Validation in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574129/error-based-on-remote-validation-in-mvc)

Comment: This was exactly the issue, thank you!  Good explanation, too.